# Accessing variables created inside a function after the function has executed

Tags: function, variables, powershell

I'm using a function which creates some variables I'd like to use after the function has processed.
I've tried accessing them directly but I can't. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Can you share the source code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Variables inside functions don't survive after the function has been run. If you want to access them after the function has processed, prefix them with a scope modifier.

```
PS> function test-var{ $script:var='foo' }
PS> test-var # excute the function
PS> $var #print var
foo
```

Type this in your console for more information:

```
PS> Get-Help about_Scopes
```

Answer (score 7):

as Shay pointed out you can create what are called global variables inside the function scope that will be available at higher level scopes. However global variables are generally not a good idea and I'd like to suggest some alternatives for you.

This is from the wikipedia [global variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_variable) page:

> They are usually considered bad practice precisely because of their
>   non-locality: a global variable can potentially be modified from
>   anywhere (unless they reside in protected memory or are otherwise
>   rendered read-only), and any part of the program may depend on it.[1]
>   A global variable therefore has an unlimited potential for creating
>   mutual dependencies, and adding mutual dependencies increases
>   complexity.

Some alternatives:

- Make the function **return** data needed by the caller. Powershell functions should generally return the data related to the noun in the Powershell function [naming convention](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/07/01/naming-and-designing-advanced-powershell-functions.aspx) of Verb-**Noun**. If you need to return other data not associated to the noun consider making a second function.

  ```
  function Get-Directories {
      param ([string] $Path)

      # Code to get or create objects here.
      $dirs = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path | where {$_.PsIsContainer}

      # Explicitly return data to the caller.
      return $dirs
  }

  $myDirs = Get-Directories -Path 'C:\'
  ```
- Use a [reference variable](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315388.aspx). A reference passes a variable's address in memory to a function. When the function changes the variable's data it will be accessible outside of the function but the variable's scope will not of been changed.

  ```
  function Get-Directories {
      param ([string] $Path, [ref] $Directories)
      $Directories.Value = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path | where {$_.PsIsContainer}
  }

  $myDirs = $null
  Get-Directories -Path 'C:\' -Directories ([ref] $myDirs)
  ```

Hope this helps. Happy coding :-)

Comment: Thank you for your thourough answer!

Answer (score 3):

If you run your function with . , the function will execute in your scope, and all of the variables defined within the function will be available to the caller.

i.e.

```
. $func
$myPrivateVariable # Now Set in the parent scope.
```

If the function is in a module, you can also use this sort of trick to access the module's scope:

```
$m  =Get-Module myModule
. $m { $myPrivateModuleVariable  }
```

Hope this Helps

Comment: Thank you! But why do you run your function with a dollar sign in front of it? Like a variable?

Comment: Because it's a sample :-)  Although, you can treat a command this way as well.   I.e. $a = Get-Command Get-Command; & $a, or a ScriptBlock:  $a = { $b = 1 }; . $a; $b